# JavaFX - How do I know where a button in a GridPane exists?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I have a fxml file which has GridPane and I wanna locate buttons in each square of the GridPane. Then I wanna show an image on a button which is just clicked. However, when a button is clicked and a method in controller is called, there seems to be no information about the location of the clicked button. Without this, I can't know what square to show an image. How can I solve this problem?

I'm using JavaFX ScneBuilder2.0.
I've already tried to make a lot of methods the number of which corresponds with the number of square in GridPane. Obviously it resulted in producing too long source file and I gave up to do that.

Here is part of controller class.

```java
//GomokuController.java
package client;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class GomokuController implements Initializable{
    @FXML private GridPane gomokuBoard;
    @FXML private Button[][] put_stone_button = new Button[15][15];

    @FXML public void put_stone(){
      //called by pushing a button in the GridPane
      //I wanna know in which square the pushed button locates.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to call the `GridPane.getRowIndex()` and `GridPane.getColumnIndex()` methods and pass in the `Button` that was clicked.

However, you will need to somehow pass the `Button` to your `put_stone()` method. In the example below, I'm passing a reference to your `Button` to the method when the button is clicked:

```
put_stone_button[0].setOnAction(event -> put_stone(put_stone_button[0])

public void put_stone(Button button){
  int row = GridPane.getRowIndex(button);
  int column = GridPane.getColumnIndex(button);
}
```

You will likely need to adapt this solution to your project as your implementation is not clear in the code you posted.

> **Side Note:** Please learn the [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and stick to them.

Comment: Thank you so much! And I need to cast the Object instance which I got by "event.getSource()" into Node type, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I did change my example, however, to pass a reference to the button itself. But if you use the `ActionEvent` parameter, you would need to cast the source to your node type, correct.

Comment: Thank you for another way of coding. And I hit on another solution. That is,  creating an anonymous class and define an event method  when I create a Button instance.  However, I think it's not so good idea from memory usage viewpoint(In my solution, every Button has its anonymous class). If possible, would you tell me other defects in my idea?